# Changing directory within a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am right now running a bash script in which i need to change my directory and execute a script from the changed directory.

I want to change my folder to `myfolder` and run `script.sh` into that particular folder.

Any way to do that in Bash?

I have already tried

```
cd myfolder
./script.sh
```

But that does not work.

Comment: you wanted to run it through bash file? right?

Comment: What error is shown when it "does not work"?

Comment: That works for me. And everyone else ever. What about it is not working? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I think what he means to tell is if he runs the code from one bash script to execute another bash script which is in another directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple as hell

`(cd myfolder && ./script.sh)`

Hope this help :)

Comment: @aditya.gupta: This is in essence the same as the one you already tried. The aspects in which it differs are not mentioned as issues in your question.

Comment: Where is script.sh located? I'm curious about how this works.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus script.sh is located inside myfolder, since in a bash script if you just write cd myfolder and in the next line write ./script.sh then it wouldn't work. I hope you get it :)

Comment: Thanks; got it. That's what I thought was happening.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
cd myfolder
./script.sh
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @aditya.gupta Try adding the following flags: -xv at the top of the script and post your error. Add those flags right aftr #!/bin/bash so like this #!/bin/bash -xv

Comment: Sorry if it doesn't work. You should have mentioned it in your question that you had already tried it before.

Comment: I think what he means to tell is if he runs the code from one bash script to execute another bash script which is in another directory.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply try this:

```
cd /absolute_path/myfolder
./script.sh
```

Specifying the absolute path makes this independent from where the script is issued.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because the other script in "myfolder" does not have permisions to execute.

```
cd myfolder
chmod 755 myscript
./myscript.sh
```

Comment: Had already made it executable. 
Anyways, this was the code which made it work
`(cd myfolder && ./script.sh)`

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. It's all the same

Comment: Nopes. Try it yourselves. 
`echo "Initially"
pwd
cd /anotherfolder
pwd`

Comment: @aditya.gupta Did you have the line #!/bin/bash at the top of your script?

Comment: @aditya.gupta Well obviously you did something wrong. We're talking about the most basic commands of bash scripting.

Comment: I think what he means to tell is if he runs the code from one bash script to execute another bash script which is in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the script located in relation to `myfolder`?  All these answers posted should work.  For instance, if `myfolder` is in root, and the script is in `/path/to/file.sh` you would need to escape first.

```
cd ../../myfolder
./script.sh
```

You could check this too by putting an `ls` in your script. If you don't see `myfolder` then you're in the wrong spot.

Is your script executable? Try a `chmod +x script.sh` and run it again.

What error messages are you getting?

Comment: I think what he means to tell is if he runs the code from one bash script to execute another bash script which is in another directory.